# How do I change the linter/formatter in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity

I'm on Ubuntu. Pushing `Ctrl + Shift + i` in VS Code auto formats the file.

I was editing a solidity contract and pushed `Ctrl + Shift + i`, VS Code didn't have a formatter configured so it asked me to pick one - I accidentally chose my JS prettifier extension instead of the solidity one. This badgered up my code by trying to use single quotes instead of double quotes (not allowed in solidity) and some other non-solidity friendly changes.

Pushing `Ctrl + Shift + i` now just auto formats with the wrong formatter with no option to pick a different one.

How can I change which linter/formatter is associated to which file types in VS Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution A:**

Press `Ctrl+Shift+P`

Then type Format Document With...

At the end of the list click on Configure Default Formatter...

Now you can choose your favorite beautifier from the list.

**Solution B:**

go to **`file`** -> **`preferences`** -> **`settings`** search for format, on the left side, click on **`Text Editor`**, the very first item on the right side is **`Editor: Default Formatter`** from the dropdown you can pick any document formatter which you installed before.